# New to trigger, need amendment

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Two table:

```
    Customer: Cus_ID, Status
    Payment: Pay_ID, Cus_ID, PaidOrNot
```

Requirement is when setting "Yes" to "PaidOrNot", then automatically set the Customer Status to "VIP".

```
    CREATE TRIGGER AutoVIP

    AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON Payment

    BEGIN

        IF PaidOrNot = Yes
        THEN UPDATE Customer set Status = VIP

    END
```

I am quite not familiar with SQL syntax, this trigger seems not working, can you help me to amend it? Thanks.

Comment: Trigger syntax will depend on the SQL implementation.

Comment: what does that mean? I use SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try this?

I have deliberately tried to make it as self-explanatory as possible.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoVIP
ON Payment
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @PaidOrNot VARCHAR(3) -- Or whatever datatype it is really
  DECLARE @CustomerId INT -- Or whatever datatype it is
  SET @PaidOrNot = (SELECT PaidOrNot FROM INSERTED)
  SET @CustomerId = (SELECT Cus_ID FROM INSERTED)
  IF @PaidOrNot = 'Yes'
  BEGIN
    UPDATE Customer set Status = VIP WHERE Cus_ID = @CustomerId
  END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, try below:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER AutoVIP
 ON Payment
 AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
 AS 
   BEGIN
     DECLARE @paid VARCHAR(5)
     DECLARE @custId INT
     SET @paid = (SELECT PaidOrNot FROM INSERTED)
     SET @custId = (SELECT Cus_ID FROM INSERTED)
     IF @paid = 'Yes'
     BEGIN
       UPDATE Customer set Status = 'VIP'
        where Cus_ID = @custId;
     END;
 END;
```